# How to insert diagonal two sided arrow

Tags: math-mode, arrows

I want to insert the following into my document:

[image: diagonal arrows]

How to do that?

I can do

```
\left| \diagup \right>
```

and

```
\left| \diagdown \right>
```

but I am looking for adding arrow tips to that. I didn't find the symbol in the latex tables, therefore asking here.

Comment: `MnSymbol` has a `\neswarrow` and a `\nwsearrow`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks! Wasn't aware of that one.  Do you want to answer the question or should we vote for it as closed - solved in the comments?

Comment: We may vote as closed – solved in the comments. Of course, if you have any difficulty making it work, feel free to ask.